# JPA Hibernate map fields from class within class to same table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a class 'Audit' that will hold the following details about an entity:

- Time Created
- Created by which application user
- Time Updated
- Updated by which application user

On the database, these fields are stored on the same table as the entity attributes. For example,

USER table:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    id                  BIGINT          NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    display_name        VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,

    active              BOOLEAN         NOT NULL    DEFAULT FALSE,

    created_time        TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_user        BIGINT          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    updated_time        TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    updated_user        BIGINT          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

USER Class:

```
@Entity(name="USER")
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Audited {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="DISPLAY_NAME", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=30)
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name="ACTIVE", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private boolean active;

    private Audit audit;
}
```

AUDIT Class:

```
public class Audit {

    private Date createdTime;

    private User createdByUser;

    private Date updatedTime;

    private User updatedByUser;
}
```

On each entity table, the audit fields will be named the same. What is the best approach in mapping these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to make the `Audit` class as `@Embeddable` entity and use it in your all entities as an `@Embedded` property, which is almost what your are doing currently.